# Will this UVLO work?

Tags: power-supply, undervoltage

I'm referring to [one answer here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/372717/how-to-detect-power-failure-and-make-micro-controller-save-data-in-eeprom)

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JyQtz.png]

What if (power supply) was 24V, the VCC is 3v3 delayed by 1 second?

If you apply power then your (power loss detect) will be higher than the Vcc rail for 1 second? I don't imagine this to end up well.

In my mind i need an (and gate) that is activated by the CPU. But that will cost one more GPIO, so we can activate it from VCC itself.

However, is that and gate really required or there is better solution?

Comment: If power was 24 volts then Vcc would be about 23 volts and frying your CPU.

Comment: Andy aka, if R1,R2 were right they will form a voltage divider and provide 3v3 to cpu

Comment: Then they won't be useful for power loss detect and, resistor dividers don't make very good and stable voltage sources.

Comment: Andy aka, thats not true, this is very common way to put high voltage signals into a gpio. its not power source to the chip it will just divide the original signal, the gpio it self will have very high impedance so it doesnt matter, originally i would replace R2 with a 3v3 zener..

Comment: I think the problem was your phrase *"provide 3v3 to cpu"*. I thought you meant provide the cpu with power. And maybe you should relabel your diagram as "supply to CPU voltage regulator" rather than *Vcc to CPU*.

Comment: its not a real schematic its just to illustrate the idea, I'm just trying to ask about sensing power loss from original input voltage if you have power sequence delay.. the schematic was actually copied from the link provided above

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103327/discussion-between-hasan-alattar-and-andy-aka).

Comment: Without a good spec, no design is good. Vmin vs time duration, & latch

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 you are talking about the Vmin of UVLO and time that the controller has until switch off ?.. but the question is more concerned about power up (ie: the signal IO pin is high but Vcc of the processor is 0v) ..

Comment: Yes so define all the specs you require.

Comment: i just said its (1 sec delay for booting up the 3v3 rail). all other specs i think are not really important ? they will be capacitor discharge calculation for on time after power loss + voltage divider calculation to define Vmin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes your circuit can work but could be improved.

> If you apply power then your (power loss detect) will be higher than
>   the Vcc rail for 1 second? I don't imagine this to end up well.

If your potential divider impedances are high enough, the current that *could* be pushed into an IO pin will be low. The data sheet will hopefully advise you that, in the event of Vcc still rising on the CPU, you should be OK. However, if you use a schottky diode from the R1/R2 node to the CPU's Vcc rail AND put an extra resistor in series with the input pin you should be fine: -

[image]

Also, if your input pin can be configured to "use" hysteresis (like a Schmitt trigger) then that would be better because, you will have more defined logic levels and most (if not all) UVLO circuits I have seen have hysteresis to prevent a series of glitchy "detections" as the supply is falling through the area where the input gate is most sensitive to non-digital levels.

Comment: thanks, this was my version, Zener instead of shottky because duplicate part,, https://snipboard.io/HS71aA.jpg ,, what do you think ?

Comment: probably R12 need to be reduced to 50k or less ..

Comment: D18 might be a bit of a spoiler in that it will be conducting above 3 volts and add more uncertainty. You don't need it. I don't understand your choice R12 and R25 values but, I guess if you do have D18 then that explains it. D17 won't make a very good schottky diode because it's forward volt drop might be 0.8 volts.

Comment: hi, so this is better: https://snipboard.io/Hg7tKv.jpg ? i know extra parts but they are less BOM list..

Comment: That won't protect the IO line because if the junction of R12 and R26 rises above 3.3 volts then what stops it rising further?

Comment: D17 will shunt that to the shunt rail .. which is (3.3 - 0.8) + Vd17 = 3.3v

Comment: What stops that shunt rail rising - just the 10 k resistor (not much protection in other words). I also note that you have a 78L24 regulator so does that mean that the minimum DC power voltage is higher than 27 volts?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103329/discussion-between-hasan-alattar-and-andy-aka).